# letsencrypt: domain was skipped due to unreachable file

Tags: lets-encrypt, directadmin

I am running 300 domains on my server they all are symlinked to the same destination. (it is a whitelabel system). every domain i add that has the correct nameservers (we own our own nameservers) works good with creating a SSL Certificate in direct admin using the letsencrypt service. But today ive added a domain (it has the correct nameservers for 7 days already, also when i use safari to skip te warning the website appears that should appear), and tried to get a Certificate and i am getting the following error (i tried every Key Size):

xxx.nl was skipped due to unreachable http://xxx.nl/.well-known/acme-challenge/ file.
[www.xxx.nl](http://www.xxx.nl) was skipped due to unreachable http://www.xxx.nl/.well-known/acme-challenge/ file.
No domains pointing to this server to generate the certificate for.

After this i added other .nl domains that ive checked for correct nameservers they worked.

hope someone knows a solution or can bring me in the right direction. thanks!